# Deep picking using Underscore.JS

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I am trying to use underscoreJs to manipulate a JavaScript object and having problems doing so.

Here is my example

```js
var data = {
  "label": "SomeName",
  "parent": [{
    "id": "parentId",
    "resources": [{
      "name": "ID1NAME",
      "calls": [
        "user_get", "user2_post", "user3_delete"
      ]
    }, {
      "name": "ID2",
      "calls": [
        "employee1_get", "employee2_delete", "employee3_update"
      ]
    }]
  }]
};
var res = _(data).chain().
    pluck('parent').
    flatten().
    findWhere(function(item){
     item === "user_get"
    }).
    value();
    
console.log(res);
```

Using an element which is a part of `data.parent.calls[]` (example : "user_get") I would like to extract its parent object, i.e. `data.parent[0]`.

I tried above but always get undefined. I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Do you have the chance of wrapping your JSON into an array? Since Underscore is using collections (which do contain an array holding up all types of objects), writing down your JSON into an array would solve your problem. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WGroRm?editors=0011

Comment: @torazburo Thanks for your suggestion. I sure know the meaning of parse and JSON. I might have wrongly used the word parse, but my intention of calling it a JSON document is correct as I have been working on a JSON document. I have given an example by skipping the part where JSON document is parsed into a Javascript object. 

Also, with due respect, manipulate word you used is not correct, extract would be nice. I am respectful of others :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the problems you're having is your use of `_.pluck`. If you execute `_.pluck` over an object, it'll go over the keys of the object trying to retrieve the property you specified as the second argument (in this case, *'parent'*). *'label'* is a string and *'parent*' is an array so thus the array that you get as a result is `[undefined, undefined]`. The rest will then go wrong.

One solution could be as follows:

```
function findCallIndexInParent(call, parent) {
    return _.chain(parent)
            .pluck('resources')
            .flatten()
            .findIndex(function (obj) {
                return _.contains(obj.calls, call);
            })
            .value();
}

function findCall(call, data) {
    var parent = data.parent;
    return parent[findCallIndexInParent(call, parent)];
}

console.log(findCall('user_get', data));
```

`findCall` is just a convenient method that will pass the parent property of data to `findCallIndexInParent` (that will retrieve the index where *call* is) and return the desired object with the *parent* array.

[Lodash](https://lodash.com/) (a fork of underscore) provides a method to get the property of an object that would have come really handy in here (sadly, underscore doesn't have it).

The explanation of `findCallIndexInParent` is as follows:

1. Chain the parent list
2. pluck the resources array
3. As pluck maps, it returns a list of lists so a flatten is needed.
4. Find the index of the element which *calls* contains *call*
5. Return the value (the index) of the object that contains *call* within *parent*.

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1f445pyg/). Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. Appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

This would seem to do the trick.

```js
function findByCall(data, call) {
  return _.find(data.parent, function(parent) {         //From data.parent list, find an item that
    return _.some(parent.resources, function(resource) {//has such parent.resource that it
      return _.includes(resource.calls, call);          //includes the searched resource.calls item
    });
  });
}

//Test

var data = {
  "label": "SomeName",
  "parent": [{
    "id": "parentId",
    "resources": [{
      "name": "ID1NAME",
      "calls": [
        "user_get", "user2_post", "user3_delete"
      ]
    }, {
      "name": "ID2",
      "calls": [
        "employee1_get", "employee2_delete", "employee3_update"
      ]
    }]
  }]
};

console.log(findByCall(data, 'user_get'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
```

Comment: I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to get the index of the element in the `parent` array which has any resource with the specified call.

```js
data = {
  "label": "SomeName",
  "parent": [{
    "id": "parentId",
    "resources": [{
      "name": "ID1NAME",
      "calls": [
        "user_get", "user2_post", "user3_delete"
      ]
    }, {
      "name": "ID2",
      "calls": [
        "employee1_get", "employee2_delete", "employee3_update"
      ]
    }]
  }]
}

// find the index of a parent 
const index = _.findIndex(data.parent, parent => 
    // that has any (some) resources
    _.some(parent.resources, resource => 
        // that contains 'user_get' call in its calls list
        _.contains(resource.calls, 'user_get')
    )
)

console.log(index) // 0
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

If you want to find the actual parent object, use `find` instead of `findIndex`

If you want to find all parent objects matching this call, use `filter` instead of `findIndex`