# Nested JSON Object not showing up when printing it

Tags: javascript, json, nest-nested-object

Not able to show deeply nested JSON Objects to show up.Have been looking at all kinds of stackoverflow posts for this. Appreciate any help on this newbie question. I want it to show details of the athlete JSONObject within the athletes array.
It shows up like [Object].

```
eventUnitResults: [ { is_team: true, athletes: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { is_team: true, athletes: [ [Object], [Object] ] } ]
```

```js
const result = {}
let eventUnitResults = [];
let athletes = [];

for (i=0; i < 2; i++) {
  const athlete = {};
  athlete.athlete_name = 'Ram' + i;
  athlete.athlete_gender = 'M'
  athletes.push(athlete);
}
for (j=0;j < 2;j++) {
  const nestedResult = {};
  nestedResult.is_team = true;
  if (athletes) {
    nestedResult.athletes = athletes;
  }
  console.log('nestedResult:', nestedResult);
  if (nestedResult) {
    eventUnitResults.push(nestedResult);//TODO:
    //eventUnitResults.push(JSON.stringify(nestedResult));//TODO:
  }
}
console.log('eventUnitResults:', eventUnitResults);//<==== how can I get deeply nested values of athletes showing up properly here

if (eventUnitResults) {
  result.event_unit_results = eventUnitResults;
}
console.log('result:', result)
```

TIA

Comment: what does the original JSON look like: hint, show the **string** before you parse it

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. *"It shows up like [Object]."* You probably mean `[object Object]`. That means you're converting the object to a string (for instance, via `document.write`, or assigning to `innerHTML`, etc.).

Comment: You are not printing JSON, you are printing an actual object that some browsers show as if being JSON. Try `JSON.stringify(eventUnitResults);`

Comment: Side note: Your snippet falls prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html): Be sure to declare your variables (such as `i` and `j`).

Comment: Use underscore js for deep picking data. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39754131/deep-picking-using-underscore-js

Comment: @Randy - JSON.stringify(eventUnitResults); worked . Thx a ton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you log your objects, you might want to convert the actual object to a string.

#### Background

If you compare this to java (or most languages):

```
System.out.println(object);
```

prints your `object.toString()`. Unless you override it, that's the memory address.

#### Problem

In JavaScript:

```
console.log(object);
```

> `[object, object]`

would print `[object, object]` because it prints WHAT you are printing. In this case, it does not know that you expect a String containing JSON.

**Note** this does not apply to all browsers. Chrome, for example, wants to help you out and prints the JSON value interactively; you can collapse and uncollapse it.

#### Solution

The solution to this problem, is telling the console explicitly to print a json string. You can do this by calling the build-in json object's function to stringify an object.

```
JSON.stringify(object);
```

> { "content": "json" }

---

For completeness, print the object pretty by setting the print output to 4 spaces indentation:

```
JSON.stringify(object, null, 4);
```

prints:

```
{
    "content": "json"
}
```

Comment: +1 & big thanks for providing details about JSON.stringify but Randy gave the right answer to the problem I had.

Comment: @Vijay that was me, detailing my comment because then you can close the question by accepting my answer ;)