# Why console.log does not show all levels of JSON after parsing?

Tags: json, parsing, console.log, stringify

I am practicing with simple APIs. I request data from OXFORD API. The data is received correctly and I can navigate through it and extract the definitions or etymologies I want. However when I print the complete response after the .json() the content of some arrays is shown as [Array]. Any Idea what I am missing?

My code looks like this:

```
let endpoint = "https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v2/entries/en-gb/ace?fields=definitions&strictMatch=false";
const   headers: {
    'app_id': app_id,
    'app_key': app_key
  }

fetch(endpoint,  {headers} )            
.then(rawResponse=>rawResponse.json())
.then(response=>{
    console.log(response);
    console.log(response.results[0].lexicalEntries[0].entries[0].etymologies[0])
    });
```

Result in the console looks like:
'''

```
{
  id: 'ace',
  metadata: {
    operation: 'retrieve',
    provider: 'Oxford University Press',
    schema: 'RetrieveEntry'
  },
  results: [
    {
      id: 'ace',
      language: 'en-gb',
      lexicalEntries: [Array],
      type: 'headword',
      word: 'ace'
    },
    {
      id: 'ace',
      language: 'en-gb',
      lexicalEntries: [Array],
      type: 'headword',
      word: 'ace'
    }
  ],
  word: 'ace'
}
Middle English (denoting the ‘one’ on dice): via Old French from Latin as ‘unity, a unit’
```

'''
I had tried with Apps Script, I got same result
'''

```
 results: 
   [ { id: 'ace',
       language: 'en-gb',
       lexicalEntries: [Object],
       type: 'headword',
       word: 'ace' },
```

'''

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about `console.log(JSON.stringify(response));` ?

Comment: Thanks know all appear but as a JSON string as stringify() method converts a JavaScript object or value to a JSON string, But still why I can't display all levels of the JavaScript object when I print the response directly through console.log(response)?

Comment: Thanks. After printing all as JSON string which is not that readable. Your reply helped me to do a second round of search and I found this printing is perfect using console.log(JSON.stringify(response,null,4)); it prints it like a JSON object. I found it on that answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47279994/nested-json-object-not-showing-up-when-printing-it

Answer (score 0):

The first comment here inspired my answer and further search. console.log() mainly prints string and when passing to it an array or an object, it interpret them as far as it can. So for the first level of `[object, object]`  or `{A:[],B:[]}` it would print it without a problem.
When we go deeper to more nested arrays and objects within the JavaScript object parsed from an API response, it won't be able to interpret it properly and would return [object] or [Array]
e.g. The following can be printed by console.log easily

```
console.log([{A:1},{B:2},{C:3}])
```

and returns

```
[ { A: 1 }, { B: 2 }, { C: 3 } ]
```

Also,

```
console.log([{A:1},{B:2},{C:3,D:[1,2,3]}])
```

easily prints

```
[ { A: 1 }, { B: 2 }, { C: 3, D: [ 1, 2, 3 ] } ]
```

But,

```
 console.log([{A:1},{B:2},{C:3,D:[{E:1},{F:2},{G:3}]}])
```

returns

```
[ { A: 1 },
  { B: 2 },
  { C: 3, D: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] } ]
```

So we need, to use `JSON.stingify` to convert it into a string

```
console.log(JSON.stringify([{A:1},{B:2},{C:3,D:[{E:1},{F:2},{G:3}]}]))
```

Successfully returns

```
[{"A":1},{"B":2},{"C":3,"D":[{"E":1},{"F":2},{"G":3}]}]
```

However, When the JSON object is bigger and deeper, you might need to prettify it using

```
console.log(JSON.stringify([{A:1},{B:2},{C:3,D:[{E:1},{F:2},{G:3}]}],null,2))
```

it returns

```
[
  {
    "A": 1
  },
  {
    "B": 2
  },
  {
    "C": 3,
    "D": [
      {
        "E": 1
      },
      {
        "F": 2
      },
      {
        "G": 3
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

You can find a reference in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 0):

If you are triggering the issue when using express.js, then it is that the express is unable to read the json values. You have to use a middleware

```
app.use(express.json())
```

this will help express understand the json values